# We have/need to save her

Tags: word-choice, difference

> We have to save her, okay? I can't live without her.

> We need to save her, okay? I can't live without her.

Will these be seen as completely interchangeable or is one more appropriate in the context than the other?

Answer (score -1):

“Must” is more emphatic than “have to,” which in turn is more emphatic than “need to.”

The subtle differences in emphasis are often ignored in speech and informal writing.

Comment: But using 'must' wouldn't be as natural as 'have to' and 'need to', right?

Comment: There is nothing unnatural about “must.” It is used far less frequently, in large part because it is needed far less frequently. “I need to see the latest Star Wars movie” may show poor taste, but “I must see the latest Star Wars” movie demonstrates insanity.